# FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections HEROKU

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to a postgreSQL database on heroku:

```
FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Yesterday I was working with this database and everything went fine, today morning it started to fail, I saw the settings on heroku and everything is fine. I can't create a ticket on heroku because this is a FREE account. Is this a heroku error or I have to do something to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: 'I saw the settings on heroku and everything is fine'. What 'settings' did you see, and what about them indicated everything was fine?

Comment: Heroku sets some user settings for default such as user, database, host etc, those are delivered by heroku and are the ones I use to connect either from code or dbeaver. This error was solved this morning somehow, I don't know how but it did. Now I am experimenting other errors, maybe the problem is postgresql in heroku.